# How to typecheck a .js file that uses Vue using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a small .js file using Vue that I want to be type-checked with the TypeScript compiler:

```
function main() {
    new Vue({
        el: 'ts-message',
        template: '<div>Hello</div>',
    });
}
```

If I try to typecheck it with `tsc`, the compiler complains it cannot find the declaration for `Vue` even though I have the `vue` npm package installed:

```
$ tsc --allowJs --checkJs --noEmit src/main.js 
src/main.js:6:9 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Vue'.

6     new Vue({
          ~~~
```

How do I tell the TypeScript compiler to auto-detect the `Vue` global object or to import it explicitly in the JS file?

## Other things I tried

If this `main.js` file is renamed to `main.ts` and I add the following line to the top, then the TypeScript compiler succeeds:

```
import Vue from "vue";
```

Unfortunately I need to typecheck **JavaScript** files specifically and I cannot add such a line to the top of a JavaScript file, since browsers do not recognize that kind of import syntax.

Comment: You can do that with a typing file containing global augmentation.

Comment: @unional I tried a few variations on the following but got various errors:

export {};
declare global {
    import Vue from "vue";
    export default Vue;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For vue <= 2.5.17

Create a `src/vue.shims.d.ts` file with the following content:

```
import VueConstructor from 'vue';
declare global {
    const Vue: typeof VueConstructor;
}
```

Then compile it along with the original `src/main.js` using:

```
$ tsc --allowJs --checkJs --noEmit src/main.js src/vue.shims.d.ts
```

It works!

### For vue 2.5.18 thru 2.6.10

Open `node_modules/vue/types/index.d.ts` and comment out the following line:

```
export as namespace Vue;
```

replacing it with:

```
//export as namespace Vue;  // interferes with vue.shims.d.ts
```

Now you can use the `vue.shims.d.ts` file mentioned earlier in this answer.

**Caution:** Modifying a dependency in place is quite a brittle approach. If possible I'd recommend upgrading Vue instead.

### For vue > 2.6.10

The development version of Vue has a [closed issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vuejs.org/issues/2042) and [merged PR](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/pull/9912) that makes it possible to use `Vue` as a global from within a script so long as you explicitly include Vue's types definitions.

Install a development version of Vue:

```
$ npm install 'git+ssh://git@github.com/vuejs/vue.git#ab50e8e1da2f4f944af683252481728485fedf16'
```

Now compile the JS script along with the `vue/types/index.d.ts` file.

```
$ tsc --allowJs --checkJs --noEmit src/main.js node_modules/vue/types/index.d.ts
```

Comment: It seems this solution only works for vue@2.5.17 and below. In particular this solution does not work for 2.5.18 or the latest 2.6.10. -- 2.5.18 introduced the line "export as namespace Vue;" in its top-level index.d.ts. I'm going to investigate further...

Comment: Apparently in vue@2.5.18 the `vue/types/index.d.ts` was modified to add the line `export as namespace Vue;`. If I remove this line then the shim presented in this answer works again. Unfortunately modifying a dependency like Vue directly is brittle so I'm still looking for a better solution.

Comment: In that case, try to do `declare module 'vue' {...}` it may work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. create a `typings/vue.d.ts`

```
// typings/vue.d.ts
import Vue from 'vue'

export as namespace Vue
```

2. Include the `typings` folder in your `jsconfig.json`:

```
// jsconfig.json
{
  "include": ["typings"]
}
```

I have not use Vue.js myself. My assumption is that its typings does not expose `Vue` globally.

The file above gets the type from `vue` and expose it as a namespace.

Comment: With the additional vue.d.ts, I get a compiler error on main.js, pointing at the "new Vue({" line: error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature. -- I suspect that `Vue` when exported as a "namespace" cannot be used as a constructor anymore.

Comment: Yes. That make sense. I was thinking about the types. You also need to declare the variable. Let me check.

Comment: Try adding `declare const Vue: typeof VueExport` in that file. and rename import to `import VueModule from 'vue`.

Comment: You probably also need `esModuleInterop` in your config.

Comment: I got the same compiler error with those modifications, however `declare const Vue: typeof VueExport` was enough of a hint that I was able to derive a provisional answer! https://stackoverflow.com/a/56822240/604063

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to declare the Vue.js via a vue.shims.d.ts file in the main source folder(`src` folder for example).

Something like this:

```
declare module "*.vue" {
    import Vue from "vue";
    export default Vue;
}
```

Comment: That shims file appears to modify how tsc interprets *.vue files, but there are no *.vue files in this example. I tried to modify the first line to say `declare module "*.js" {` instead but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I tell the TypeScript compiler to auto-detect the `Vue` global object or to import it explicitly in the JS file?

You could do this with a module bundler that invokes the TypeScript compiler, or use a CDN. No manual typings (`*.d.ts`) are necessary in your case.

#### Module Bundler

In order to use npm packages in the browser, you need a module bundler (such as [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org), or [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/)) to create a script that includes those packages.

I highly recommend using [Vue CLI](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html) to automatically scaffold a TypeScript project, which includes Webpack. A few advantages of this generated project:

- allows using [`import`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import) (or [`require`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#require)) in your scripts even when targeting browsers, as the build output would automatically bundle the imported packages
- minimizes [JavaScript fatigue](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-manage-javascript-fatigue) by using sensible defaults that are easily configurable
- provides IDE support (e.g., via [Vetur](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/) in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)) that includes automatic type-checking as you code

### CDN

If you prefer not to use a module bundler, you could import the third-party scripts from a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) into the global scope with a `<script>` tag *before* your own script runs. For instance, to import Vue and Vue-Router from [unpkg](https://unpkg.com), your `index.html` could contain this:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@3.0.6"></script>

<script src="./main.js"></script>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
  }),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```